# JAVA: how to interrupt function if it last more than 1 sec

Tags: java, time, interrupt

I have such code in my program

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    func(i);
}
```

For most values of i, func lasts less than 1 sec, but for some values it may last several minutes, so I need to interrupt it if it lasts too long.

How can I do that?

Comment: What does `func(int i)` do? You could limit overall execution time from this snippet (somewhat), but it sounds like you want to limit an individual call and continue to the next if too much time is being spent inside a particular `func(i)` call.

Comment: I can't do anything inside func(i). It generates pseudo random sequences of numbers based on input. Is there another way to do that?

Comment: show your func method

Comment: Whatever func is, you can use the custom exception handling as shown below.

Answer (score 2):

FutureTask is perfect for executing code with timeout.

```
    FutureTask task = new FutureTask(new Callable() {
        @Override
        public Object call() throws Exception {
            /* Do here what you need */
            return null; /* Or any instance */
        }
    }) {
    };
    try {
        Object result = task.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Example1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Example1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Example1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to interrupt a function that may take too long is by running it in a separate thread. You can then send a message to that thread after a second to tell it to stop. Without using threads, you could handle it by replacing func with the code below:

```
function process(int i, long maxMiliseconds) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(System.currentTimeMillis() - start < maxMiliseconds) {
        //do your processing one step at a time
        // return an answer if you have one.
    }
    //make some record of the fact that the process timed out for i.
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start func() in a separate thread and then do method `join(long millis)` on your thread to wait for 1 second for it's ending. But still the thread will run until it finish (`stop()` method is deprecated). The means of this is to get control in your current thread and react appropriately

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I see it. I am sure there are ways to do it in less lines of code, but this one is straightforward solution

If you would want to run your `func(i);` in `Thread` then it would be another story.

```
public class MainClass {
    private static boolean riding, updated = false;


    private static int timeout = 10000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            if (!riding){
                long endTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeout;
                func(endTimeMillis);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void func(long endTimeMillis) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9999; i++) {
            if ((!riding && System.currentTimeMillis() < endTimeMillis) || updated) {
                updated = false;
                System.out.println("run method main function");
                riding = true;
            } else {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " > "
                        + endTimeMillis);
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() > endTimeMillis) {
                    updated = true;
                    System.out.println("overdue");
                    riding = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        riding = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can inject your exception handling into func if you dont want another thread.**

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
{


        try 
        {
           func(1);
        } 
        catch (timeR e) 
        {
             System.out.println("enough!")
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();

        }

}


    static void func(int a) throws timeR //your func needs to throw something when time-is-up
    {
       long time1,time2;             //reference time and current time
       time1=System.nanoTime();      //having reference
       time2=System.nanoTime();      //init of current
       while(true)                   //You did not put your func, so I used inf-while
       {
            //here whatever your func does,
                //.....
                //.....
            //below line checks if time is up
            time2=System.nanoTime();
            if((time2-time1)>1000000000)   //1000000000 is 1 second or 1Billion nanoseconds
            { throw new timeR("time is up!");} 
            //this is throwing(an alternative exit from this function)
       }

    }

    static class timeR extends Exception
    {
      //Parameterless Constructor

       public timeR() 
       {

       }

       //Constructor that accepts a message
       public timeR(String message)
       {
          super(message);
       }
    }
```

Output: 1 second after func() called:

```
enough!
proje.lineerCebir$timeR: time is up!
at proje.lineerCebir.func(lineerCebir.java:198)
at proje.lineerCebir.main(lineerCebir.java:179)
```

**Maybe you dont want to see red messages, then just comment out the e.printStackTrace().**
Have fun.